# En la cocina mexicana, ¿qué es "pimienta chica"?/ In Mexican cooking, what is "pimienta chica"?

Tags: vocabulario, méxico, comida

I recently watched [Pollito Enchilado De Mi Rancho A Tu Cocina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUD0Tw3rD5E), and one of the spices used was "pimienta chica."  Pimienta negra was also used, so it sounds like this is something different from black pepper.

To make matters more confusing, a lot of Mexican websites selling spices list "pimienta negra chica," so I'm not sure if it's just a smaller black peppercorn or a different variety of pepper entirely.

So, what is pimienta chica in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the **pimienta negra chica** or **pimienta chica** is what is known in English as *peppercorn*.  There is a different spice, **pimienta gorda**, which is known in English as *allspice*.

My first source was an article at https://www.imco.mx/productos/pimienta-gorda/.  It was corroborated at https://www.laprensagrafica.com/mujer/Los-tipos-de-pimienta-20140317-0154.html.  Next I did a google images search for `pimienta negra chica y pimienta gorda comparison` (I know, I suddenly switched languages in the middle of the search phrase -- but hey, it worked).  I found the following helpful image, which used to be posted at https://ok-salud.com/ but which is no longer there.  **Warning** for the squeamish: please be aware that there are images of endoparasites on the home page of ok-salud.com.  At any rate, the comparison picture of the two spices is quite helpful:

[image: dos pimientas]

In the video you watched (thanks for the link!) she clearly adds three separate spices ("pimienta chica, pimienta negra y un poquito de clavos").  So it seems this cook's name for these two spices doesn't match up exactly with what I found.  At any rate, her recipe seems to include black pepper, allspice and cloves.

Food names vary from one region to another more than anything else I know.  It could be a regional thing or it could be that she misspoke, or that she has her own pet names for these spices.  I did check some online recipes, and what I commonly found was "pimienta negra" and "pimienta gorda" (listed as separate ingredients).

(I wish someone would get Doña Ángela a deeper wooden spoon so she has an easier time fishing the round tomato halves out of the hot oil....)

¡Buen provecho!